# Trying to run Android Studio and get this error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

My project builds and the emulator opens correctly, but I get this error in the logcat:

Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.navigatingu/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory

I can't find any of these files or directories in my project, so I'm not sure what to do. The app does not start at all, and the emulator just sits at the android home screen.
I've restarted my computer and done "Invalidate Cache and Restart", none of these work to fix it.

I was expecting the app to start running, because it had been working a few minutes before the error started occuring.

Comment: code_cache must be cleared. It's not in your project it's on the device, in your case the emulator. It looks like it has unsync between your code and the cache.
You can try to revert to previous code version when it was working. 
Restarting the computer should not magically cleared a folder. "Invalidate cache and restart" I dont' remember if this applies to the android studio or to the emulator.